# Merge 2 arrays, keep it sorted, and find efficiency

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, merge

So, I found an interesting problem where you are given 2 sorted arrays and your task is to combine them into a new array and keep it sorted. Also, find the efficiency of your program. I got my code working, but I'm not sure about the efficiency.. I think it is O(n) as I use a while loop to iterate through every element of the array(s). Any tips? Is there a way to make this even more efficient? Is O(n) correct? Here is the code:

```
class mergesorted{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        int[] x = { 1, 3, 7};
        int[] y = { 2, 4, 5, 6, 15};
        int[] retrieval =  answer(x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < retrieval.Length; i++){
            Console.WriteLine(retrieval[i]);                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int[] answer(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        int[] a = x;
        int[] b = y;
        int abc = 0; //counter for a
        int abc2 = 0; //counter for b
        int i = 0; //counter for index of new array
        Boolean flagA = true; //if flag changed, array is exhaused
        Boolean flagB = true;
        int[] newarray = new int[a.Length+b.Length]; //so size is 7

        while (abc < a.Length && abc2 < b.Length){
            if (a[abc] < b[abc2]){
                newarray[i] = a[abc];
                abc++;
            }
            else{
                newarray[i] = b[abc2];
                abc2++;
            }

            if (abc >= a.Length){
                flagA = true;
                flagB = false;
            }

            else if (abc2 >= b.Length){
                flagA = false;
                flagB = true;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (flagA == false){
            while (abc < a.Length){
                newarray[i] = a[abc];
                abc++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if (flagB == false){
            while (abc2 < b.Length){
                newarray[i] = b[abc2];
                abc2++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return (newarray);
    }
}
```

Comment: And which language after all?

Comment: Sorry. I wrote this in c#

Comment: how could it be more efficient than O(N)? you have to visit each item once.

Comment: That's true, but for N < 10, cant you implement a nlogn algorithm and make it more efficient? I'm not sure if that is expected though..

Comment: If you can guarantee n < 10 you really shouldn't care about the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Isn't it theta(N)? Moreover, if you keep this algorithm for every case, it cannot be do better than O(N).

Comment: Are you also going to accept duplicates of a value into the new array or do you keep just one copy of the duplicate?

Comment: Your algo. is not taking advantage of sortedness of two input arrays. If you do that the code will cleaner as you wont require flags. You got to take approach exactly similar to merge function used in merge sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of redundant testing. But your algorithm is O(N), since it touches each element once. You cannot do better than that (in the general case) since building the final array is O(N).

In the special case where one array is much larger than the other and you have an O(1) insert (or move) operation, you can make an algorithm that's O(A log B), where A is the number of entries in the smaller list and B is the number of entries in the larger list. For example, if one array has 1,000,000 objects and the other only has 2, you can just use a binary search to figure out where, in the 1,000,000 object list, to move each of the two objects in the other list. If the two lists are about the same size, this doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to write a quick algorithm to do this task and didn't go back to fix up redundancy. The special case you said makes sense. I guess you could have a special method to compute that if that case occurs

Comment: If the inserts are O(1), then you must be working with a linked list so the search must be O(n) or O(log n) if you use some hybrid linked list-array.
On an array the insert is usually O(n) so I don't think you can get O(A log B) in practice, since inserting the elements of B will still be O(b) in the general case. I can only imagine your solution being better then O(n) with special data structures, with arrays is will most likely be O(n) or worse.